# How to order by a group of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been asked to create a list of franchises that have the most revenue grouped by years, however the order by clause needs to order by franchises who have had the most revenue depending on the date range. I can order them by the single sum(revenue) fine but how do I order the franchise groupings by revenue?

```
group by
    vFranMasterNumRollup.MasterFranNumber, 
    REPLACE(vFranMasterNumRollup.FranchiseName, ',', '') ,
    YEAR(vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_ServiceDate)
order by
    sum(vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_LaborRevenue) desc,
    REPLACE(vFranMasterNumRollup.FranchiseName, ',', '')
```

you see here I've tried to add another column to the ordering but I want to keep the highest franchise group together in the descending order

Let me know if you need any more code

Here is more of the code:

```
SELECT     vFranMasterNumRollup.MasterFranNumber, REPLACE(vFranMasterNumRollup.FranchiseName, ',', '') AS FranchiseName, 
sum(vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_LaborRevenue),YEAR(vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_ServiceDate) 
FROM         vremittheaderdetailandfran INNER JOIN
                      vFranMasterNumRollup ON vremittheaderdetailandfran.remh_FranchiseNumber = vFranMasterNumRollup.fran_FranchiseID
WHERE     (vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_ServiceDate BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate AND (vFranMasterNumRollup.fran_Status = N'ACTIVE') OR
                      (vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_ServiceDate BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate))
group by vFranMasterNumRollup.MasterFranNumber, 
REPLACE(vFranMasterNumRollup.FranchiseName, ',', '') , YEAR(vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_ServiceDate)
order by sum(vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_LaborRevenue) desc,REPLACE(vFranMasterNumRollup.FranchiseName, ',', '')
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want something like this:

```
ORDER BY
   SUM(SUM(vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_LaborRevenue))
     OVER (PARTITION BY vFranMasterNumRollup.MasterFranNumber),
   REPLACE(vFranMasterNumRollup.FranchiseName, ',', '')
```

The `SUM(…) OVER (…)` thing is a windowed aggregate function. This particular windowed `SUM()` calculates the totals over the entire range specified in your `WHERE` clause, grouping (partitioning) them by `vFranMasterNumRollup.MasterFranNumber` (which I understood was a sort of franchise unique identifier).

The argument of a windowed `SUM()` is typically a column or an expression containing column references, just like it is with the "normal" `SUM()`. In this case, you can see another `SUM()` as the argument. The other `SUM()` is a "normal" aggregate function. We have to reference the aggregated value of `vremittheaderdetailandfran.remd_LaborRevenue` instead of the column directly, because this is a `GROUP BY` query and the column in question is not included in the `GROUP BY` clause. As a result, the entire expression reads as "sum of sums of `remd_LaborRevenue`", which makes perfect sense in this context, I guess.

You can read more about windowed aggregate functions in the [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) manual.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using group by, you will need to order by any of the columns that participate on the grouping or one of the aggregate columns (SUM for example)

Also, you don't need to add the full aggregation function on the order by, you can simply do "order by" and add the index of the column. For example:

```
select columns1, column2, sum(coulm3)
from table1
group by columns1, column2
order by 3
```

will order by the SUM

Comment: Order by 3, 2 is the same as what I have

Comment: I want the query to return the highest franchise group ordered by sum(revenue) for the franchise and list all franchise revenues

Comment: I want them ordered descending by franchise who has sum(overall all years revenue) and the year(revenue) listed by year